# Overflow Scroll css is not working in the div

Tags: css

I am looking for CSS/Javascript solution for my HTML page scrolling issue.

I have three divs that contain a div, a header and a wrapper div,

I need a vertical scrollbar in the wrapper div, height should be auto or 100% based on the content.

The header should be fixed, and I don't want overall scrollbar so I have given `overflow:hidden` in the body tag,

I need vertical scrollbar in my wrapper div. How can I fix this?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%
}

#container {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #dadada;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 1000px;
  overflow: scroll;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div class="header"></div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Vivamus porta tortor sed metus. Nam pretium. Sed tempor. Integer ullamcorper, odio quis porttitor sagittis, nisl erat tincidunt massa, eu eleifend eros nibh sollicitudin est. Nulla dignissim.
      Mauris sollicitudin, arcu id sagittis placerat, tellus mauris egestas felis, eget interdum mi nibh vel lorem. Aliquam egestas hendrerit massa. Suspendisse sed nunc et lacus feugiat hendrerit. Nam cursus euismod augue. Aenean vehicula nisl eu quam
      luctus adipiscing. Nunc consequat justo pretium orci. Mauris hendrerit fermentum massa. Aenean consectetuer est ut arcu. Aliquam nisl massa, blandit at, accumsan sed, porta vel, metus. Duis fringilla quam ut eros.</p>
    <!-- Lots more paragraphs-->
  </div>

</div>
```

Please refer to this [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZcrFr)

Answer (score 262):

You are missing the `height` CSS property.

Adding it you will notice that scroll bar will appear.

```
.wrapper{ 
    // width: 1000px;
    width:600px; 
    overflow-y:scroll; 
    position:relative;
    height: 300px;
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZcrFr/8/)

From [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y):

## `overflow-y`

> The overflow-y CSS property specifies whether to clip content, render a scroll bar, or display overflow content of a block-level element, when it overflows at the top and bottom edges.

Comment: how to make the height stop at the viewport? I don't want to hardcode in pixels, since it does't work for different screen sizes

Comment: @djechlin Ask a question for that. Probably you can use percent values or `dislpay: fixed`... I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: use the viewport height property: height: 100vh

Answer (score 69):

The solution is to add `height:100%;` to all the parent elements of your `.wrapper-div` as well. So:

```
html{
    height: 100%;
}

body{ 
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:100%;
}

#container{
    width:1000px;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Hello, I know it's been 7 years but I'm here to ask how this works? Why is it like this? Or is this some typical CSS trick that 'just' works.

Comment: If you set the height of a element in percentages, then that percentage refers to the height of its parent. If the parent has no height set to it, it will refer to the closest ancestor that has a set height. If no ancestor with a set height is found, the percentage is a percentage of nothing. And 100% of nothing is nothing. I found an interesting article on the subject here: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/html-page-width-height/

Comment: How would someone add a scrollbar to a `div` that is deep inside a dialog layout with size controlled by "flex"?  There's no fixed height and it's not practical to add `height` to every surrounding `div` but the scrollbar is necessary because the space is likely not large enough for its text content.

Answer (score 33):

If you add height in `.wrapper` class then your scroll is working, without `height` scroll is not working.

Try this 
http://jsfiddle.net/ZcrFr/3/

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 800px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but my actual requirement is i should not give any height may be can give 100% or auto, the content should take according to the browser window, can u any other solution in CSS/JAVASCRIPT ?

Comment: why it's not working when I given height in percentage as `height:100%`

Answer (score 9):

You didn't gave the div a height. So it will automatically stretch when more content is added.
Give it a fix-height and the scroll bars will show up.

Comment: Thanks, but my actual requirement is i should not give any height may be can give 100% or auto, the content should take according to the browser window, can u any other solution in CSS/JAVASCRIPT ?

Comment: Give it a height of 100%. Then you meet the requirements for overflow and yourself.

Answer (score 8):

If you set a static height for your header, you can use that in a calculation for the size of your wrapper.

http://jsfiddle.net/ske5Lqyv/5/

Using your example code, you can add this CSS:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

#container {
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  height: 64px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.wrapper {
  height: calc(100% - 64px);
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Or, you can use flexbox for a more dynamic approach
http://jsfiddle.net/19zbs7je/3/

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="section">
    <div class="header">Heading</div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <p>Large Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

html, body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.section {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 0;
}

.header {
  height: 64px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: auto;
  min-height: 100%; 
}
```

And if you'd like to get even fancier, take a look at my response to this question
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52416148/1513083

Answer (score 8):

in my case, only `height: 100vh` fix the problem with the expected behavior

Answer (score 7):

I edited your: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZcrFr/7/)

```
html, body{ margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; height:100% }
.header { margin: 0 auto; width:500px; height:30px; background-color:#dadada;}
.wrapper{ margin: 0 auto; width:500px; overflow:scroll; height: 100%;}
```

Giving the html-tag a 100% height is the solution.
I also deleted the container div. You don't need it when your layout stays like this.

Comment: Thanks its working, but am using coder slider concept its having main container div, the header area i have three div should fixed, inside wrapper content area only should be scrolling, You said remove the container so how can i fix this issue any other way pl ?

Answer (score 3):

I made the required changes and now it will work. Please check the below changes I made to ".wrapper":

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  max-height:100vh;
  max-width:100vw;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

And below is the result:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%
}

#container {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #dadada;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  max-height:100vh;
  max-width:100vw;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div class="header">
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Vivamus porta tortor sed metus. Nam pretium. Sed tempor. Integer ullamcorper, odio quis porttitor sagittis, nisl erat tincidunt massa, eu eleifend eros nibh sollicitudin est. Nulla dignissim. Mauris sollicitudin, arcu id sagittis placerat, tellus mauris egestas felis, eget interdum mi nibh vel lorem. Aliquam egestas hendrerit massa. Suspendisse sed nunc et lacus feugiat hendrerit. Nam cursus euismod augue. Aenean vehicula nisl eu quam luctus adipiscing. Nunc consequat justo pretium orci. Mauris hendrerit fermentum massa. Aenean consectetuer est ut arcu. Aliquam nisl massa, blandit at, accumsan sed, porta vel, metus. Duis fringilla quam ut eros.</p>
    <p>Sed eu ligula eget eros vulputate tincidunt. Etiam sapien urna, auctor a, viverra sit amet, convallis a, enim. Nullam ut nulla. Nam laoreet massa aliquet tortor. Mauris in quam ut dui bibendum malesuada. Nulla vel erat. Pellentesque metus risus, aliquet eget, eleifend in, ultrices vitae, nisi. Vivamus non nulla. Praesent ac lacus. Donec augue turpis, convallis sed, lacinia et, vestibulum nec, lacus. Suspendisse feugiat semper nunc. Donec nisl elit, varius sed, sodales volutpat, commodo in, elit. Proin ornare hendrerit lectus. Sed non dolor. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Duis suscipit. Mauris egestas tincidunt lectus. Phasellus sed quam et velit laoreet pretium. Nunc metus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Vivamus porta tortor sed metus. Nam pretium. Sed tempor. Integer ullamcorper, odio quis porttitor sagittis, nisl erat tincidunt massa, eu eleifend eros nibh sollicitudin est. Nulla dignissim. Mauris sollicitudin, arcu id sagittis placerat, tellus mauris egestas felis, eget interdum mi nibh vel lorem. Aliquam egestas hendrerit massa. Suspendisse sed nunc et lacus feugiat hendrerit. Nam cursus euismod augue. Aenean vehicula nisl eu quam luctus adipiscing. Nunc consequat justo pretium orci. Mauris hendrerit fermentum massa. Aenean consectetuer est ut arcu. Aliquam nisl massa, blandit at, accumsan sed, porta vel, metus. Duis fringilla quam ut eros.</p>
    <p>Sed eu ligula eget eros vulputate tincidunt. Etiam sapien urna, auctor a, viverra sit amet, convallis a, enim. Nullam ut nulla. Nam laoreet massa aliquet tortor. Mauris in quam ut dui bibendum malesuada. Nulla vel erat. Pellentesque metus risus, aliquet eget, eleifend in, ultrices vitae, nisi. Vivamus non nulla. Praesent ac lacus. Donec augue turpis, convallis sed, lacinia et, vestibulum nec, lacus. Suspendisse feugiat semper nunc. Donec nisl elit, varius sed, sodales volutpat, commodo in, elit. Proin ornare hendrerit lectus. Sed non dolor. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Duis suscipit. Mauris egestas tincidunt lectus. Phasellus sed quam et velit laoreet pretium. Nunc metus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Vivamus porta tortor sed metus. Nam pretium. Sed tempor. Integer ullamcorper, odio quis porttitor sagittis, nisl erat tincidunt massa, eu eleifend eros nibh sollicitudin est. Nulla dignissim. Mauris sollicitudin, arcu id sagittis placerat, tellus mauris egestas felis, eget interdum mi nibh vel lorem. Aliquam egestas hendrerit massa. Suspendisse sed nunc et lacus feugiat hendrerit. Nam cursus euismod augue. Aenean vehicula nisl eu quam luctus adipiscing. Nunc consequat justo pretium orci. Mauris hendrerit fermentum massa. Aenean consectetuer est ut arcu. Aliquam nisl massa, blandit at, accumsan sed, porta vel, metus. Duis fringilla quam ut eros.</p>
    <p>Sed eu ligula eget eros vulputate tincidunt. Etiam sapien urna, auctor a, viverra sit amet, convallis a, enim. Nullam ut nulla. Nam laoreet massa aliquet tortor. Mauris in quam ut dui bibendum malesuada. Nulla vel erat. Pellentesque metus risus, aliquet eget, eleifend in, ultrices vitae, nisi. Vivamus non nulla. Praesent ac lacus. Donec augue turpis, convallis sed, lacinia et, vestibulum nec, lacus. Suspendisse feugiat semper nunc. Donec nisl elit, varius sed, sodales volutpat, commodo in, elit. Proin ornare hendrerit lectus. Sed non dolor. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Duis suscipit. Mauris egestas tincidunt lectus. Phasellus sed quam et velit laoreet pretium. Nunc metus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Vivamus porta tortor sed metus. Nam pretium. Sed tempor. Integer ullamcorper, odio quis porttitor sagittis, nisl erat tincidunt massa, eu eleifend eros nibh sollicitudin est. Nulla dignissim. Mauris sollicitudin, arcu id sagittis placerat, tellus mauris egestas felis, eget interdum mi nibh vel lorem. Aliquam egestas hendrerit massa. Suspendisse sed nunc et lacus feugiat hendrerit. Nam cursus euismod augue. Aenean vehicula nisl eu quam luctus adipiscing. Nunc consequat justo pretium orci. Mauris hendrerit fermentum massa. Aenean consectetuer est ut arcu. Aliquam nisl massa, blandit at, accumsan sed, porta vel, metus. Duis fringilla quam ut eros.</p>
    <p>Sed eu ligula eget eros vulputate tincidunt. Etiam sapien urna, auctor a, viverra sit amet, convallis a, enim. Nullam ut nulla. Nam laoreet massa aliquet tortor. Mauris in quam ut dui bibendum malesuada. Nulla vel erat. Pellentesque metus risus, aliquet eget, eleifend in, ultrices vitae, nisi. Vivamus non nulla. Praesent ac lacus. Donec augue turpis, convallis sed, lacinia et, vestibulum nec, lacus. Suspendisse feugiat semper nunc. Donec nisl elit, varius sed, sodales volutpat, commodo in, elit. Proin ornare hendrerit lectus. Sed non dolor. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Duis suscipit. Mauris egestas tincidunt lectus. Phasellus sed quam et velit laoreet pretium. Nunc metus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Vivamus porta tortor sed metus. Nam pretium. Sed tempor. Integer ullamcorper, odio quis porttitor sagittis, nisl erat tincidunt massa, eu eleifend eros nibh sollicitudin est. Nulla dignissim. Mauris sollicitudin, arcu id sagittis placerat, tellus mauris egestas felis, eget interdum mi nibh vel lorem. Aliquam egestas hendrerit massa. Suspendisse sed nunc et lacus feugiat hendrerit. Nam cursus euismod augue. Aenean vehicula nisl eu quam luctus adipiscing. Nunc consequat justo pretium orci. Mauris hendrerit fermentum massa. Aenean consectetuer est ut arcu. Aliquam nisl massa, blandit at, accumsan sed, porta vel, metus. Duis fringilla quam ut eros.</p>
    <p>Sed eu ligula eget eros vulputate tincidunt. Etiam sapien urna, auctor a, viverra sit amet, convallis a, enim. Nullam ut nulla. Nam laoreet massa aliquet tortor. Mauris in quam ut dui bibendum malesuada. Nulla vel erat. Pellentesque metus risus, aliquet eget, eleifend in, ultrices vitae, nisi. Vivamus non nulla. Praesent ac lacus. Donec augue turpis, convallis sed, lacinia et, vestibulum nec, lacus. Suspendisse feugiat semper nunc. Donec nisl elit, varius sed, sodales volutpat, commodo in, elit. Proin ornare hendrerit lectus. Sed non dolor. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Duis suscipit. Mauris egestas tincidunt lectus. Phasellus sed quam et velit laoreet pretium. Nunc metus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Vivamus porta tortor sed metus. Nam pretium. Sed tempor. Integer ullamcorper, odio quis porttitor sagittis, nisl erat tincidunt massa, eu eleifend eros nibh sollicitudin est. Nulla dignissim. Mauris sollicitudin, arcu id sagittis placerat, tellus mauris egestas felis, eget interdum mi nibh vel lorem. Aliquam egestas hendrerit massa. Suspendisse sed nunc et lacus feugiat hendrerit. Nam cursus euismod augue. Aenean vehicula nisl eu quam luctus adipiscing. Nunc consequat justo pretium orci. Mauris hendrerit fermentum massa. Aenean consectetuer est ut arcu. Aliquam nisl massa, blandit at, accumsan sed, porta vel, metus. Duis fringilla quam ut eros.</p>
    <p>Sed eu ligula eget eros vulputate tincidunt. Etiam sapien urna, auctor a, viverra sit amet, convallis a, enim. Nullam ut nulla. Nam laoreet massa aliquet tortor. Mauris in quam ut dui bibendum malesuada. Nulla vel erat. Pellentesque metus risus, aliquet eget, eleifend in, ultrices vitae, nisi. Vivamus non nulla. Praesent ac lacus. Donec augue turpis, convallis sed, lacinia et, vestibulum nec, lacus. Suspendisse feugiat semper nunc. Donec nisl elit, varius sed, sodales volutpat, commodo in, elit. Proin ornare hendrerit lectus. Sed non dolor. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Duis suscipit. Mauris egestas tincidunt lectus. Phasellus sed quam et velit laoreet pretium. Nunc metus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Vivamus porta tortor sed metus. Nam pretium. Sed tempor. Integer ullamcorper, odio quis porttitor sagittis, nisl erat tincidunt massa, eu eleifend eros nibh sollicitudin est. Nulla dignissim. Mauris sollicitudin, arcu id sagittis placerat, tellus mauris egestas felis, eget interdum mi nibh vel lorem. Aliquam egestas hendrerit massa. Suspendisse sed nunc et lacus feugiat hendrerit. Nam cursus euismod augue. Aenean vehicula nisl eu quam luctus adipiscing. Nunc consequat justo pretium orci. Mauris hendrerit fermentum massa. Aenean consectetuer est ut arcu. Aliquam nisl massa, blandit at, accumsan sed, porta vel, metus. Duis fringilla quam ut eros.</p>
    <p>Sed eu ligula eget eros vulputate tincidunt. Etiam sapien urna, auctor a, viverra sit amet, convallis a, enim. Nullam ut nulla. Nam laoreet massa aliquet tortor. Mauris in quam ut dui bibendum malesuada. Nulla vel erat. Pellentesque metus risus, aliquet eget, eleifend in, ultrices vitae, nisi. Vivamus non nulla. Praesent ac lacus. Donec augue turpis, convallis sed, lacinia et, vestibulum nec, lacus. Suspendisse feugiat semper nunc. Donec nisl elit, varius sed, sodales volutpat, commodo in, elit. Proin ornare hendrerit lectus. Sed non dolor. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Duis suscipit. Mauris egestas tincidunt lectus. Phasellus sed quam et velit laoreet pretium. Nunc metus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Vivamus porta tortor sed metus. Nam pretium. Sed tempor. Integer ullamcorper, odio quis porttitor sagittis, nisl erat tincidunt massa, eu eleifend eros nibh sollicitudin est. Nulla dignissim. Mauris sollicitudin, arcu id sagittis placerat, tellus mauris egestas felis, eget interdum mi nibh vel lorem. Aliquam egestas hendrerit massa. Suspendisse sed nunc et lacus feugiat hendrerit. Nam cursus euismod augue. Aenean vehicula nisl eu quam luctus adipiscing. Nunc consequat justo pretium orci. Mauris hendrerit fermentum massa. Aenean consectetuer est ut arcu. Aliquam nisl massa, blandit at, accumsan sed, porta vel, metus. Duis fringilla quam ut eros.</p>
    <p>Sed eu ligula eget eros vulputate tincidunt. Etiam sapien urna, auctor a, viverra sit amet, convallis a, enim. Nullam ut nulla. Nam laoreet massa aliquet tortor. Mauris in quam ut dui bibendum malesuada. Nulla vel erat. Pellentesque metus risus, aliquet eget, eleifend in, ultrices vitae, nisi. Vivamus non nulla. Praesent ac lacus. Donec augue turpis, convallis sed, lacinia et, vestibulum nec, lacus. Suspendisse feugiat semper nunc. Donec nisl elit, varius sed, sodales volutpat, commodo in, elit. Proin ornare hendrerit lectus. Sed non dolor. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Duis suscipit. Mauris egestas tincidunt lectus. Phasellus sed quam et velit laoreet pretium. Nunc metus.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

I know I'm late, but I hope someone finds it helpful.

Answer (score 3):

**solution**:
overflow just working with
**display: block;**

```
.container{ 
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

and use this tutorial for overscroll-behavior from **Google**:
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/11/overscroll-behavior

Comment: no, its the height rule that makes it work.  The author of the question already has a div element which is display block by default

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to comment on @Ionica Bizau, but I don't have enough reputation.
To give a reply to your question about javascript code:
What you need to do is get the parent's element height (minus any elements that take up space) and apply that to the child elements.

```
function wrapperHeight(){
    var height = $(window).outerHeight() - $('#header').outerHeight(true);
    $('.wrapper').css({"max-height":height+"px"});      
}
```

**Note**
window could be replaced by ".container" if that one has no floated children or has a fix to get the correct height calculated. This solution uses jQuery.

Comment: It's a CSS problem why use Javascript?

Comment: Because the OP asked for CSS/Javascript solution. There was already a good CSS solution and I believe at the time the OP asked in a comment on the most voted answer on how to do it in JS. But it's been a few years so I might remember wrong ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In case others are having trouble getting @Ionică Bizău's answer to work, you may want to also add **pointer-events: auto;** to the wrapper with overflow: scroll

```
.wrapper {
    pointer-events: auto;
    position: relative;
    overflow: scroll;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 800px;
}
```

If wrapper has a parent with `pointer-events: none`, the scroll won't work. Possibly will save someone some time.

Answer (score 1):

in my case stylling it inline with "styles" parameter was the problem, when i created class for div and then styled it it worked, and yes you need to specify height

Answer (score 0):

These all solution are good , but if you want to add vertical scroll and don't want to change div height then you can use `margin-top:40px;` like that to take all the things in position and so it can remain in container and scroll nicely
and update the margin-top value as per you requirements.

thanks

Answer (score -1):

got the same issue, but fixed with min-width and min height

min-height:'value'
min-width:'value'

I know that this issue is old but in case you encountered this issue you can try that.

Comment: Min-height does work, you need a to give a height

Comment: For others, can you explain where to put `min-height` and `min-width`? Otherwise the answer is too vague.

Answer (score -2):

Try this for a vertical scrollbar:

```
overflow-y:scroll;
```

Comment: But if you are on a Mac with only trackpad, this would not work either.

Comment: The author of the question alerady has overflow set to scroll, he's missing a height rule

Answer (score -3):

For Angular2 + Material2 + Sidenav, you'll need to do the following:

```
 ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.element.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName('md-sidenav-content')[0].style.overflow = 'hidden'; 
  }
```

Comment: any more details on that? why couldn't you just put `overflow:hidden` in `css` in case of material2?

Comment: You are not answering the actual question here, that was not about angular nor material nor about making overflow hidden. So IMHO you answer is misplaced here.