# How to make <table> scrollable and not overlap header or footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, razor

[image: Page layout]

Hello,
There is page layout what I failed to implement.
I cant get that  content scrollable, so that it does not go under header/footer.
I set  to overflow:hidden, and tried set  or *(table container)* to *overflow-y:scroll*. In that case table have scrollbar grayed out and content partly hidden. 
And if I set  that is container for footer/header and  to *overflow-y:scroll*, table content go under header that make it unreadable.
Does anyone have any suggestions?
Thank you.

Comment: do you use bootstrap? if not, try it! it's simply easy!

Comment: Please share a code what you have done so far

Comment: and write some code that you tried as a fiddle or a snippet so that it would be easy for understanding the exact scenario.

Comment: share your code please ?

Comment: Found it! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17295219/overflow-scroll-css-is-not-working-in-the-div .So just need to add *height* to table container.