# Material UI grid with independent scrolling columns

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm looking to make multiple scrolling columns using Material UI in React. I had a way of doing it in bootstrap with flex, but I can't get it to translate over. I have put together a demo of a hacky way to do it that requires knowing the size of the contents above what you're trying to scroll (in this case, the AppBar)

https://codesandbox.io/s/pmly895mm

```
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#root {
  height: 100%;
}

.grid-container {
  height: calc(100% - 64px);
}

.grid-column {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

In this demo, I set all of the heights to 100% (html, body, #root) and then created two classes `grid-container` with a height of 100% - AppBar height and `grid-column` with a height of 100% and an overflow-y of auto.

In Bootstrap, I would apply these classes to the `row` and `column` elements respectively

```
.flex-section {
  flex-grow: 1;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  min-height: 0;
}

.flex-col-scroll {
  flex-grow: 1;

  overflow: auto;

  min-height: 100%;
}
```

And it wouldn't matter what was above the elements because flex took care of the heights.

Specifically, I am looking to avoid having to do `height: calc(100% - 64px)` as this requires me knowing the element heights beforehand. I'm going to have some pages where I'd like to put some content above the scrolling area that will have dynamically tall content.

Comment: do you want to apply css through jss ?

Comment: @SakhiMansoor I know how to translate this into JSS, that's not the issue. I'm looking for a more dynamic way of accomplishing this. I'm going to have some pages that will have more than just the AppBar at the top and I'd rather not calculate the heights of the elements (especially if it can vary). That's what I liked about using flexbox for this.

Comment: I'm still not sure what's your actual concern. Sorry for the misread. You code works fine even replacing calc with 100% height only

Comment: Sorry i'm not being clear enough. When you remove the calc and just do 100%, you end up with some extra scroll at the bottom. You're stuck scrolling down to the bottom of the column, and then there's 64px leftover which then you can scroll again and it hides the AppBar https://codesandbox.io/s/kow9ww5kj5

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In my determination to recreate how I used to do it in bootstrap (https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/226591/) I was actually able to get it working in Material UI as well. And since I wasn't able to find any sort of examples of this online for this specific use case (React / Material UI scrollable columns), hopefully this will help someone else.

Here is the example: https://codesandbox.io/s/z24wl3n58m

```
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#root {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-section {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 0;
}

.flex-col-scroll {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.flex-no-shrink {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

What I was missing was setting the flex on the root. Once we do that, then we can utilize `flex-section`, `flex-col-scroll`, and `flex-no-shrink` (the latter of which is used to prevent elements above the scrolling from being compressed)

Comment: Thank you for sharing your resolution. It helped me a lot. For material-ui 1.5.1 I had to add `flex-wrap: nowrap` to flex-section class. Also I needed to remove `flex-direction: column`.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have one issue though... if the text in the h1 tags are just a little longer, it seems to fall apart. Can you help?

Comment: This helped a lot! Thanks very much.

Answer (score 23):

### 2020 Update

FWIW I was just able to add these two style properties to a `Box` component to achieve a scrollable `<div>` column:

```
<Box style={{maxHeight: '100vh', overflow: 'auto'}}>...</Box>
```

Comment: Works with `Grid` too

Comment: Davis thank you!
@yogesnsamy unless you center it vertically xD

Answer (score 2):

You just need to make your navbar fixed. It will remain intact to the top. After that, add a padding to you `grid container` which is going to have all your content. You can even give percentage padding to make sure responsiveness.

Here is the working codesandbox: [Fixed Navbar](https://codesandbox.io/s/p9pxqpnx57)

Let me know if the issue still persists.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is a perfect example of what I am trying to achieve. However, I do not think that making the bar fixed vs static would help. Now that it's static, you have to add padding to each view just to remove the overlap. Moving on, you added some text above the initial grid. That's great. That's what I also want to be able to do. But, as you can see, there is another scroll bar now on the main view as well as the two columns. This can be compensated for by adding `height: calc(100% - 36px);` to `.grid-container` to compensate for the extra space from the new lines

Comment: However, this brings me back to my initial issue where I do not want to have to calculate / determine the height of the content above my scrollable content; it would amazing if I were able to do it dynamically as was done with flexbox. I'm going to put together an example of how it worked in bootstrap. Maybe that will help.

Comment: I actually think I figured it out in my determination to create my bootstrap version (see here: https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/226591/)

Answer (score 1):

I found it really difficult to do this with Material UI's Grids because, as was pointed out in a comment to another one of the answers, it doesn't seem to be achievable without "flex-wrap: nowrap", and adding "flex-wrap: nowrap" breaks Material UI's grid layout system.

I did find, however, that I could reproduce Josh Sherman's [Layout with fixed header and independently scrolling columns](https://joshtronic.com/2015/05/03/layout-with-fixed-header-and-independently-scrolling-columns/) fairly easily if I used Material UI's Boxes instead of Grids.

In index.html:

```
<style>
  body,
  html,
  #root {
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>
```

#root is, of course, created by create-react-app.

And in App.tsx:

```
import React from "react";
import { AppBar, Box, Toolbar } from "@material-ui/core";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <AppBar>
        <Toolbar />
      </AppBar>
      <Box flexDirection="column" display="flex" height="100%">
        <Toolbar />
        <Box flexGrow={1} display="flex" overflow="hidden">
          <Box overflow="auto">
             <!-- The contents of the left column go here -->
          </Box>
          <Box overflow="auto">
            <!-- The contents of the right column go here -->
          </Box>
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```