# scroll overflow in Burger Menu

Tags: css, overflow

I need to scroll overflow **in burger menu** when one of the spoilers is open.

I add **overflow: auto** to the container and **height** for it, but it doesn't work.

Please check the screenshots I attached:
[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jr6WB.jpg)
[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxH9t.jpg)

[My Website](https://icookyoueat.ru/domain/)

`HTML`

```html
<div class="burger-menu-container">
    <nav class="burger-menu">
        <div class="spoiler-mob">
            <div class="spoiler-mob-item"><a>Header 1</a></div>
            <div class="spoiler-mob-data" id="spoiler-mob-data">
                <a href="">link1</a><br>
                <a href="">link2</a><br>
                <a href="">link3</a><br>
                <a href="">link4</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="spoiler-mob">
            <div class="spoiler-mob-item">
            <a>Header 2</a>
            </div>
            <div class="spoiler-mob-data" id="spoiler-mob-data">
                <a href="">link1</a><br>
                <a href="">link2</a><br>
                <a href="">link3</a><br>
                <a href="">link4</a>
            </div>
        </div>                                    
        <div><a>Header 3</a></div>
        <div class="spoiler-mob">
            <div class="spoiler-mob-item"><a>Header 4</a></div>
            <div class="spoiler-mob-data" id="spoiler-mob-data">
                <a href="">link1</a><br>
                <a href="">link2</a><br>
                <a href="">link3</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div><a>Header 5</a></div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

`CSS`

```css
    .burger-menu-container {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        height: 17rem;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    
    .burger-menu {
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17295219/overflow-scroll-css-is-not-working-in-the-div) you can find more information. But, to answer your question, this would be the possible fixes in your case.

1. You add a fixed height on your `.burger-menu` class, and `overflow-y: scroll`. It will work in this way, but you will have that fixed height that might bother you (this depends on you).
2. You make the menu on mobile to be positioned absolutely, with 100% width and height, but I think you will have to move it from where it is now, in order to make it position absolutely, in relation with the body.

Or you leave it as it is, because with the current number of links in the menu, there won't be cases (while browsing the website, on mobile, in portrait mode), when the menu won't fit in the viewport. The case you presented in your image with the 768x393 screen size, will simply never happen.